# String Manipulation in c with delimiter \322

Tags: c, char

I have the following code where I need to find substring of str and compare with str1 and str2 individually :

```
char *str = "abcdefgh\322qwerty";
char *str1 = "abcdef";
char *str2 = "qwerty";

if(strcmp(str,str1))
   res = 1;
if(strcmp(str, str2))
   res = 2;
else 
   res = 0;
```

I am unable to suggest how to consider /322 as it is considered as a char when I print str[8] is \322. So, splitting is difficult to perform. Please help.

Comment: What does "I need to substring str" mean?

Comment: Find substring of str or can say split the str and match each one of them with str1 and str2

Comment: `\322` is an octal character with decimal value 210, which is `Ò` on my system. If you want to find where it is, just iterate through the string looking for `'\322'`

Comment: You don't need to care about this character at all.  You can use `strstr` to find substrings, and then split accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for this is to use strstr. It will return NULL if the substring does not exist in your str. Otherwise, it will return the pointer of that substring in str.

```
char *str = "abcdefgh\322qwerty";
char *str1 = "abcdef";
char *str2 = "qwerty";
int res;

if( strstr(str,str1) != NULL )
    res = 1;
else if( strstr(str, str2) != NULL )
    res = 2;
else
    res = 0;

printf("%d\n", res);
```